# Hibernate: Issue with OnDelete Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Hello
I have the following two entities

```
@Entity
public class DocumentCollection {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(targetEntity=Document.class,mappedBy="documentCollection",cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
  private Set<Document> documents;
 ...
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
public class Document {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private DocumentCollection documentCollection;
  ...
}
```

When a DocumentCollection gets deleted, all referenced documents should be deleted too.
But I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`tms_db`.`document`, CONSTRAINT `FK3737353BEB85533C` FOREIGN KEY (`documentCollection_id`) REFERENCES `documentcollection` (`id`))
```

I also tried putting the @OnDelete Annotation in the document class but didn't work.
So what am I missing? For your information, I'am using Hibernate 3.6.0.Final.

UPDATE: I did a mysql schema dump and noticed that there is no ON DELETE CASCADE statement in the document table schema. Hibernate only generates the foreign key constraints, which leads to the mentioned error. Has anybody an idea why hibernate does NOT generate the "ON DELETE CASCADE" statement?

Hope, somebody can help me
thx

Answer (score 3):

`@OnDelete` annotation affects the way Hibernate generates database schema. If your schema is not generated by Hibernate, or haven't been updated after adding this annotation, it wouldn't work correctly.

If you want to use manually created database schema with `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)`, you should manually define foreign key constraint in your schema as `on delete cascade`.

Comment: thx for your reply, where can I find the schema that is generated by hibernate?

Comment: @krebbl see your foreign key.